# Is it possible to fine grain different types of notifications in Nagios?

Tags: nagios

I wondered if I could fine tune Nagios notifications

For example:

- For most services, only CRITICAL notifications
- For some individual services, both CRITICAL and WARNING notifications
- For some other services, no notifications at all

I mean like something default, for all servers, not defining this one by one

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Check https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/objectdefinitions.html#hostgroup

Comment: Two hours ago I was thinking if services had like some kind of notification in config or something like that and I thought I was going to search for some docs so this is definitely what I need

Comment: The configuration option you want is `notification_options`, and if you don't want to set it for every object (host/service) you can set it in a template, then use that template for all (or some) objects.